# Parse newline, white space, and "\" character with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, json

everyone hope things are going well. I'm trying to remove newline and "\" character from a string that I have after applying JSON.stringify();. The string looks like so:

```
"[{\n    \"id_profile\": 1, \n    \"name\": \"John\"\n    \"id\" : \"894J45134R90FM\",\n...
```

I've gotten as far as removing "\n" using `.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,' ')` but I'm having trouble targeting the "\" character. My goal is to eventually use parseJSON(); to turn this into a JSON object for DOM manipulation.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to structure the regex within replace? I believe the spaces should be tab delimited, this is coming from an Apiary API GET request. Does this need to be in a separate replace function?

Thank you greatly for any help.

Comment: "I'm trying to remove newline and "\" character from a string that I have after applying JSON.stringify()" --- for what? PS: how exactly did you get such a weird output?

Comment: @Bergi has the right answer to your question, `JSON.parse` will solve all your problems, there shouldn't be a need for using a RegExp to parse the data from your `GET` request (that wouldn't make for a very user-friendly API, now would it)

Comment: @zerkms: Looks like `JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify([{"id_profile":1,"name":"John","id":"894J45134R90FM"}], null, 4))`

Comment: @Bergi: oh my god :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a string literal there which contains valid JSON. Just call `JSON.parse()` directly on it, there's no need to replace anything!

In case you're reading in the string literal as a string, you will need to call `JSON.parse` twice - once to get a string from the JSON string, then to get the array from that string. Or better make your api output the JSON array instead of string literals containing JSON in the first place, there seems to be one `JSON.stringify()` too much somewhere.

Comment: "output JSON instead of string literals" --- JSON is a string literal actually

Comment: Yes, JSON can be a JSON string literal as well, but usually JSON text consists of JSON array or object literals (which may contain strings).

Comment: I see now what you mean, but it's worded in a confusing way.

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org/) is a data serialisation format. You might read it from a file, or put it inside a string *literal* in your program, which will both result in a string containing the JSON at runtime. (Unfortunately?) the JSON format is specified to be built of "literals", which adds a lot of confusion. The term "JSON string" can both refer to "a string containing JSON-formatted data" or "a string (literal) in a JSON text".

Answer (score 2):

I think you should modify the component that is creating this output.

But if that isn't an option, you can target a "\" by escaping it first: `\\`.

This will remove the "\n" and "\" characters from your output:

`.replace(/[\n\\]/g, '');`

If you also want to remove the whitespace, target the `\s` metacharacter as well:

`.replace(/[\n\\\s]/g, '');`